# CustomView, Mac, Swift, let myEmptyView = self.moveView(frame: viewRect) viewRect cannot be found

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, custom-view

I am playing with custom View in Swift on Mac.

I have set up custom view in the mac window, I have linked to the swift file and in the swift file I have the following:

```
import Cocoa

class moveView: NSView {
    override func drawRect(rect: NSRect)  {

        NSColor.greenColor().setFill()

        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)

        path.fill()
    }
let viewRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let myEmptyView = self.moveView(frame: viewRect)
```

Now, when I am trying to compile with the last line as it is, I get:

> /Users/tony/Documents/test/test/ViewController.swift:21:19: 'moveView
>   -> () -> moveView' does not have a member named 'moveView'

I am not sure why (I am using the o'Reilly's book Swift Development with Cocoa.

Can you please explain how comes that I target the case in which I am and it will not get found? If I remember self, the error message is quite similar...

> /Users/tony/Documents/test/test/ViewController.swift:21:35:
>   'moveView.Type' does not have a member named 'viewRect'

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code must be placed inside a method of your class. Put it inside viewdidload to check. This will give you the idea.

```
let myEmptyView = self.moveView(frame: viewRect)
```

Of course the one above must go there as well

```
let viewRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Just move both these lines of code into the viewdidload method. In case you do not want it there, Put them into any other method you need after confirming it works inside a method.